# When I segue another page, the top of the navigation bar turns black SWIFT 5

Tags: ios, swift

When I click on the search icon, I segue another page and added the search bar to the navigation bar.But after making a segue, the top of the navigation bar turns black.

Before segue:

[image: screenshot before segue]

After segue:

[image: screenshot after segue]

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupSearch()                    
    }
        
    func setupSearch() {
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1333333333, green: 0.1333333333, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1333333333, green: 0.1333333333, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of `segue` are you performing? Is it in storyboard or you are performing it programatically?

Comment: Programatically.     @IBAction func searchButtontapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSearchVC", sender: self)
        
    }

Comment: Ok, and what type of segue is that? `show` or `present Modally`? Check it by going to storyboard and clicking on the segue with identifier `toSearchVC` and then go to attributes inspector and look under `kind` tab,

Comment: segue type is show.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding edge for extended layout either from code like below

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.all
```

Or You can do it from the XIB/Storyboard as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

storyboard -> navigation controller - > untick the shows navigation bar and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding backgroundcolor to my view.

```
view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1333333333, green: 0.1333333333, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
```

Then I added another white view. I don't know if this is the right way, but the problem is solved.

[image: storyboard side menu screenshot]

[image: UI screenshot]